# Named capture groups with grep

Tags: regex, grep, capture-group

I use Unix grep. I would like to know how can I handle named capture groups with it.

Currently this is what I have:

`echo "foobar" | grep -P "(?<q>.)ooba(?<w>.)"`

So in theory, I have `q=f` and `w=r`, however I don't know how can I use these variables or hand them over to the next command (for example awk) via the pipeline.

In the end, I would like to have the following result:

`f r`

The above string is just an example. The capture groups could be anywhere, could be in any number, and printing could also be in any order. I'm saying this because I'm not specifically looking for a way to extract the last and the first character of a string, but rather an approach to extract as many variables as I want from a string. I know tricks like using `-o`, `\K` or `(?<=some text).*?(?=some other text)`, but these only extract one portion of the string and not multiple.

Comment: grep does not give access to capture groups at all.

Comment: it would help if you can form a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation of 9 captured groups in `sed`. However, this is not the case with `gawk`.

From Question you mentioned,*"but rather an approach to extract as many variables as I want from a string"*.

`sed` is best for the job if you have to are playing with 1-9 groups. If this is not the case `match` function of `gawk` is also helpful. (Using same regex as Inian)

```
echo "foobar" | awk '{match($0,/^(.)(.+)(.)$/,a);print a[1],a[3]}'
f r
```

PS: This is an alternate approach could be really helpful if dealing with groups more then 9. Also, for lesser number it work just fine. Also there are tightly coupled with `awk`'s variables like `NR`,`OFS` ,`FS` so formatting is easier.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` does not have the capabilities to print using *named* captured groups. Using `sed` with *regular* captured groups (not named) for your given example,

```
echo "foobar" | sed 's/^\(.\)\(.\+\)\(.\)$/\1 \3/'
f r
```

which literally means, match the first character - rest of the string and last character. Now you can access the individual captured groups from `\1`..`\n` notation,

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nUkOro/1)

The reason for `\` around the braces are because `sed` by default uses BRE (Basic RegEx) and *not*  ERE (Extended RegEx) which can be enabled using the `-E` or `-r` flag. The ERE is not supported in `POSIX` `sed` so basically the answer simulates ERE tokens from BRE by escaping them with `\`

Comment: This is not named capture group in your example.

Comment: Yeah but OP asked for named capture groups. Your `sed` example also didn't use named capture groups.

Comment: @QkiZ I modified the text to indicate, that my answer is not using named captured groups